# Creating a stored procedure for insert update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to create a stored procedure for insert/update in a very single call

Here is my start :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[OutlookDataInsert] 
    @transactionID VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @jsonRequest NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL,
    @jsonResponse NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS
    SELECT transactionID  
    FROM dbo.OutlookData 
    WHERE @transactionID IS NULL 
       OR transactionID = @transactionID
```

I want to check if `transactionID` exists and already in the database table, I should do an update, else it should do an insert. I am getting lost in the *if else* clause and a checkpoint as to how should I do this task?

Comment: https://sqlperformance.com/2020/09/locking/upsert-anti-pattern